# Best Practice searching for item in 3 nested populated arrays in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to build Sales report with 3 nested populated array , when I want to search for item in the third nested array I use forEach in each array , is there a better way or mechanism for better performance ,because the array in the future it may contains more than 20K Element, here is an example of the code :-

```
years.forEach((year) ->{
   //Actions for year object
   year.months.forEach((month) -> {
      //Actions for month object
      month.days.forEach((day) -> {
         //Actions for day object
      });
   });
});
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of how each array could look like (structure)?
Also include an example of the expected output

Comment: Please create a [mcve]

Comment: Questions about code here should ALWAYS include the relevant code you currently have to show us exactly what you're trying to accomplish.  Only then, can we understand exactly what you're trying to do and provide a precise answer.  Without code, we end up having to make long generic descriptions and guess exactly what you're trying to do - neither of which are good.

Comment: I have edited the post with code example , thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this, because you won't have to iterate through all elements when you find the item you want.

```
function performAction(years) {
  var year = years.find(y => someProp === 'ex');
  //perform what you want if year here
  var month = year.months.find(m => m.someProp === 'ex');
  //perform what you want if month here
  var day = month.days.find(d => d.someProp === 'ex');
  //perform what you want if day here
}
```

Of course, I don't know exactly how are your objects, that is why I used the 'someProp' example, you must substitute to fit to your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the javascript find funcion instead of foreach function.

E.g.:

```
const inventory = [
  {name: 'apples', quantity: 2},
  {name: 'bananas', quantity: 0},
  {name: 'cherries', quantity: 5}
];

function isCherries(fruit) { 
  return fruit.name === 'cherries';
}

console.log(inventory.find(isCherries));
```

You can read more about the find funcion here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: find will create new object from the filtered array , is there a similar way without creating new object ?

Comment: Do you need to use foreach to perform some action? The code that you provided shows that yes, if you need to iterate through every element, the find function is of no use for you. If you don't want to use any of the functions that belong to the funcional programming paradigm (like the find, filter, etc, function), I don't know what are you wanting. Please try to explain better what do you really want, and the limitations that your code must have, so I can try to specify a better answer for you.

Comment: thanks for your helping, I got the idea let me explain to you what exactly I want , I have array of years inside each year there's array of months and inside each month I have array of days, when new order create I must search for the years ,month and day he belong to and make some actions in each object , the problem is even when the year , month or day found forEach keep searching in the arrays , how can I stop this when the first condition is true? thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Now I understand what you want. I am going to answer another answer to try to show how can you accomplish what you want.